# To create different embedding layers in keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, embedding, word-embedding

I recently read this paper [End-To-End Memory Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08895) which uses three different embeddings layers for sentence embeddings. Now I am trying to reproduce this architecture in keras.

But I am not sure how to create three different embeddings. These are exactly same dimension based on same corpus but should have different values for the embeddings. So to implement this layers, should I just use [Embedding Layers](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) with `kernel_initializer =random_uniform`?

I know pre-trained embeddings like Word2Vec, but currently *pre-trained* model is not important, is it?